# Does the C/C++ memory model allow atomics at different granularities for the same bytes?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Suppose that I have the following type:

```cpp
struct T {
  int32 high;
  int32 low;
};
```

Is it defined behavior to perform atomic accesses (using, e.g. `atomic_load`, `atomic_fetch_add`) on all of `x`, `&x->high`, and `&x->low` (assuming `U* x`)?

My understanding is that the C/C++ memory models are defined using histories of over individual locations (to accommodate weak memory architectures). If accesses can cross locations, does this mean synchronization across locations? If that is the case, then I assume that would imply that histories are essentially per-byte and accessing an `int` is just like synchronizing across the underlying 4 (or 8) bytes.

**edit**: revised the example to avoid the union since the main part of the question is about the concurrency model.

**edit**: revised to use the standard atomics from `stdatomic.h`

Comment: Just to clarify, you are not asking about type punning here? Because that's not allowed in C++.

Comment: Not sure whether a _language-lawer_ question should ask about non-Standard functions such as `__atomic_xxx`.

Comment: These are the only primitives that I'm aware of for doing atomic operations. Are there standard functions for atomic operations?

Comment: `Are there standard functions for atomic operations?` [Yes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) and [yes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). [__atomic* functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) (as the double `_` suggest) is a gnu extension.

Comment: There is the [`std::atomic` class template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) which does contain methods like `fetch_add` which is I believe something that you want to use ?

Comment: `If accesses can cross locations, does this mean synchronization across locations?` what does that mean?  `high` and `low` are not bitfields. What is a "location"?

Comment: The C and C++ memory models do not allow for atomic *functions* in some general sense. They have atomic *types*, upon which you can perform atomic operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C11/C18 (I cannot speak about C++) the **Standard** `atomic_xxx()` functions of `<stdatomic.h>` are only defined to take `_Atomic` qualified arguments.  So to do `atomic_xxx()` operations on the fields of your `struct T` you would need:

```
struct T {
  _Atomic int32 high;
  _Atomic int32 low;
} ;

struct T foo, bar ;
```

and then you would be able to do (for example) `atomic_fetch_add(&foo->high, 42)`.  But `bar = atomic_load(&foo)` would be undefined.

Conversely, you could have:

```
struct T {
  int32 high;
  int32 low;
} ;

_Atomic struct T foo ;
        struct T bar ;
```

and now `bar = atomic_load(&foo)` is defined.  But access to any individual field in `foo` is undefined -- whether or not it's `_Atomic`.

Going by the Standard, `_Atomic xxxx` objects should be thought of as entirely distinct from "ordinary" `xxxx` objects -- they may have different sizes, representations and alignments.  Casting an `xxxx` to/from an `_Atomic xxxx` is, therefore, no more sensible than casting one `struct` to/from another, different `struct`.

**But**, for gcc and the `__atomic_xxx()` built-ins, you can do whatever the processor will support.  Indeed, for gcc the (otherwise) standard `atomic_xxx()` will accept arguments which are *not*`_Atomic` qualified types, and are mapped to the built-ins.  clang, on the other hand, treats passing a *not* `_Atomic` qualified type to the standard functions as an error.  IMHO this is a bug in gcc's `<stdatomic.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Loading an inactive union member yields an indeterminate value regardless of using or not using `__atomic_load` to do that load.